# How do you protect yourself from missing comma in vertical string list in python?

Tags: python

In python, it's common to have vertically-oriented lists of string. For example:

```
subprocess.check_output( [
  'application',
  '-first-flag',
  '-second-flag',
  '-some-additional-flag'
] )
```

This looks good, readable, don't violate 80-columns rule... But if comma is missed, like this:

```
subprocess.check_output( [
  'application',
  '-first-flag'  # missed comma here
  '-second-flag',
  '-some-additional-flag'
] )
```

Python will still assume this code valid by concatenating two stings :(. Is it possible to somehow safeguard yourself from such typos while still using vertically-oriented string lists and without bloating code (like enveloping each items inside `str()`)?

Comment: My only suggestion is always leave a trailing comma on lists - python allows it and it is the most common way for this error to occur (extending a list with new items and forgetting to add it in).

Comment: You could also put the comma at the start of the string. For me, it is more readable that way. Or is this not pythonic?

Comment: @DarianLewin That isn't common among python programmers. It's not necessarily a bad thing, but people may find it awkward.

Comment: on occasion: `""" a b c ...""".split()`. It is not to protect against the missing comma exactly; It is just more readable (less line noise) sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could wrap each string in parens:

```
subprocess.check_output( [
  ('application'),
  ('-first-flag'),
  ('-second-flag'),
  ('-some-additional-flag'),
] )
```

And btw, Python is fine with a trailing comma, so just always use a comma at the end of the line, that should also reduce errors.

Answer (score 5):

You can have commas at the end of a line after whitespace, like this:

```
subprocess.check_output( [
   'application'           ,
   '-first-flag'           ,
   '-second-flag'          ,
   '-some-additional-flag' ,
] )
```

Doing it that way looks a little worse, but it is easy to spot if you have missed any arguments.

Comment: This is [recommended against in PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements) - while it is a guide, you might find that other's find this awkward to read/write if they use/contribute to your code.

Comment: Hence the warning about it being messy, I often use it when I am first writing a file, and doing the bulk of the debugging, once that is done, I go through and make the syntax and style conform to the recommended standard.

Comment: @Perkins Sounds like a good strategy if that style helps you.

Answer (score 3):

maybe for *this* particular case:

```
arglist = 'application -first-flag -second-flag -some-additional-flag'
arglist = arglist.split()
subprocess.check_output(arglist)
```

Or if you find yourself writing many unique lists like this make a macro that concatenates lines into a list form, so you avoid manually putting the comma.

Comment: Will not work if some arguments have spaces. And in real-world scenarios they will :(.

Comment: @Eye of Hell in that case split on `|` ,  `'item1| -item2| -item3'.split('|')`. My pylinter in sublime tells me when it detects a missing comma.

Comment: Will not work if arguments contain `|` character etc. The suggested solution with parentheses seems a good solution for general case.

Comment: VIM, Emacs or Visual Studio 2010 - it depends on task. Sometimes Eclipse, but i rarely use it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another alternative:

```
subprocess.check_output('''
application
-first-flag
-second-flag
-some-additional-flag
'''.split())
```

Let Python insert the commas for you, this is especially useful for long lists of strings in configuration files

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using Pylint with the following configuration in `.pylintrc`:

```
[tool.pylint.string]
check-str-concat-over-line-jumps = true
```

In VS Code the Pylint extension together with the Error Lens extension provide a reliable combination:

[image: VS Code with Pylint and Error Lens]